# VueJS Use VNode inside render function with createElement?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to render a Vnode inside my render function. In such a way that I can still give that element children.
I know you can have an array of Vnodes as the third argument of createElement(tag, data, vnode[]) but since I want to give this specific Vnode children still I seem to be a little stuck,

I have tried doing something like:

```
const vnodeObj = {tag: vnode.tag, data: vnode.data}
```

//Skip to inside render function
createElement(vnodeObj.tag, vnodeObj.data, []).

Which worked well to create the tag but I have found that the data object returend from Vnode.data is not the same for the data object createElement expect for example:

If I were to add a class "test" and a ref "test2" to a element using create element the data object would look like so:

```
{
 attrs: { class: "test", ref: "test2"},
}
```

while the Vnode.data would return something like:

```
{
 "ref":"test2",
 "staticClass":"test"
}
```

Leading me to believe there must be a better way to render a single Vnode and its data and continue giving it children with createElement.